# Help with rewriting an URL with an .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

I need a .htaccess that will show this URL:

> http://www.mysite.com/es/wp-content/plugins/mailpress/mp-includes/action.php?action=mail_link&add=123&lang=es

but will in fact serve this URL:

> http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/mailpress/mp-includes/action.php?action=mail_link&add=123&lang=es

Note that action.php can receive other GET parameters in the URL. The htaccess must be able to foward them too. The only difference between these 2 URL is the "fake" root directory which will reflect the "lang" GET parameter.

Is it possible to do such things with a .htaccess (I'm pretty sure it's possible)? Anyone have pointers on how to do this??

Thanks!

**Edit1:** I forgot to say that the rewrite rule should be only valid for "action.php" that is in "/wp-content/plugins/mailpress/mp-includes/".

**Edit2:** I have this currently in my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/es/(.+)$ /$1
```

With regard to the edit of your question, here's a modified answer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es/wp-content/plugins/mailpress/mp-includes/action.php
RewriteRule ^/es/(.+)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/es/(.*) /$1
```

[here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is the corresponding documentation from apache.

Comment: Added Edit2 to question...

Comment: where did you put the rules from dominik's answer?

Comment: On the root of the domain, at the end of the existing .htaccess

Comment: try to put it directly behind the `RewriteBase` line of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Still not working... But I think it's WordPress who is messing things up. If I comment the RewriteBase line and following, I get a 404...